Solution Incompatibility between the geolocation library and kotlin in flutter
When trying to work with the new versions of the geolocation or location packages it gives me the following error:
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.   │ │ Find the latest version on                                               │ │ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update │ │ <path-to-app>/android/build.gradle:                                      │ │ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>
This error gives us the reason that the location and geolocation packages are constantly updated and you need to access the new versions of Kotlin, so if you work with a project before  of Flutter, you may have this error, it is very easy to solve it, for this you must access to 'proyecto/android/settings.gradle' You must change the following line of code for the new version of Kotlin, which is currently V 2.0.0 and eliminate the line of code that has V 1.7.10. You must also eliminate the '+' sign.
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
  - id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
  + id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}

it should stay like this:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}

CoWith that your project should work correctly

try this answer

Thank you for sharing this solution. I can confirm that it works perfectly fine.
As for me, since I was migrating from a previous Flutter SDK version, the Kotlin dependencies were handled differently in it and the structure for android/settings.gradle was entirely contradicting and confusing. If someone encountered the same fate as me, what I did was to simply backup permissions in my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and deleted the entire android folder located at the root of my Flutter app. After that I simply ran the following command:
flutter create . --platforms android

This added the android platform again but this time with updated structure in correspondence with the new SDK. Then I copied back my permissions to the new AndroidManifest.xml and proceeded with the proposed solution above without any issue.
Hope this helps someone.
